# Some gcloud commands return UNAUTHENTICATED error

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud

I'm working on a project that is hosted on Google Cloud Platform, and I'm trying to get used to their `gcloud` cli. One thing that I really don't understand is its authentication scheme.

As an example, if I run `gcloud config configurations list`, I get a list of all my configurations:

```
PS C:\Users\username\dev\project-library> gcloud config configurations list
NAME                     IS_ACTIVE  ACCOUNT         PROJECT                  COMPUTE_DEFAULT_ZONE  COMPUTE_DEFAULT_REGION
default                  True       username@domain.com  project-dev-gcp
project-dev-local        False                           project-dev-gcp
```

Similarly, if I run `gcloud auth list`, it shows me the account that I am authenticated with:

```
PS C:\Users\username\dev\project-library> gcloud auth list
           Credentialed Accounts
ACTIVE             ACCOUNT
*                  username@domain.com

To set the active account, run:
    $ gcloud config set account `ACCOUNT`
```

But if I try to run `gcloud projects list`, I don't get a list of my GCP projects. Instead, I see an error that suggests that I am not authenticated:

```
PS C:\Users\username\dev\project-library> gcloud projects list
ERROR: (gcloud.projects.list) UNAUTHENTICATED: Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.
```

Ok, so what if I try to authenticate with `gcloud auth application-default login`?

```
PS C:\Users\username\dev\project-library> gcloud auth application-default login
Your browser has been opened to visit:

    https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?response_type=code&client_id=xxxx

Credentials saved to file: [C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\gcloud\application_default_credentials.json]

These credentials will be used by any library that requests Application Default Credentials (ADC).
ERROR: (gcloud.auth.application-default.login) UNAUTHENTICATED: Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.
```

There's that UNAUTHENTICATED error again, despite the fact that my browser opened to the login page, I chose my Google account, and then granted access to the Google Auth Library when prompted to.

The weird thing is that I actually *have* an access token:

```
PS C:\Users\username\dev\project-library> gcloud auth print-access-token
ya29.a0AfH6SMCGhGKSd39hJxfCBBNIDPGvpGjjskAKNDyH24C9TU0tG8P-FH_YL3OBJOZiqFXD4hKbVGCSNpfuwqOhB2p7uaBI_PtMuQO_Ip2fiMYHbHeLzyKKrnthFV4MqCNM_P80uQrTFy9LvvFm-kpcYFFFmh4Sam2Uoq3wsPW8m9febwFX2-4
```

Ultimately, what I'd like to do is get the kubernetes configuration so that I can interact with the cluster using `kubectl`, but of course `gcloud container clusters get-credentials` tells me that I'm not authenticated:

```
PS C:\Users\username\dev\project-library> gcloud container clusters get-credentials project-dev --region us-east4 --project project-dev-gcp
Fetching cluster endpoint and auth data.
ERROR: (gcloud.container.clusters.get-credentials) ResponseError: code=401, message=Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.
```

So what gives? How come I can't seem to do anything with `gcloud`? What causes the UNAUTHENTICATED error, and how do I fix it?

I am very familiar with the `aws` cli authentication scheme, but I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around the way that `gcloud` does things. Even though the cli isn't working, I seem to have full console access, and I know that this stuff *did* work at one point because I have accessed the kubernetes cluster logs using `k9s` in the past.

Comment: What is you user (username@domain.com) role at project layer? If it's not owner please assigned it owner role and give a try

Comment: To authenticate the CLI use `gcloud auth login` to use your user credentials or `gcloud auth activate-service-account` to use a service account. `gcloud auth application-default login` is for the SDKs and non-Google tools (this is called ADC - Application Default Credentials).

Comment: Confirmed that my role is `Owner` using the IAM section of the web console. I have tried to do `gcloud auth login`, and although that appears to succeed, it doesn't solve the problem. I still get the unauthenticated error when trying to do `gcloud projects list` or `gcloud container clusters list`

Answer (score 7):

Figured out the problem. It seems my `[default]` profile at `C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\gcloud\configurations\config_default` contained some bad config values that were causing the issue:

```
[core]
account = username@domain.com
project = project-dev-gcp

[compute]

[auth]
disable_credentials = true

[spanner]
instance = project-local

[api_endpoint_overrides]
spanner = http://localhost:9020/
```

The unauthenticated problem in OP was caused by `disable_credentials = true`, and the contents of the `[api_endpoint_overrides]` section would have caused similar problems if I were trying to interact with Google Cloud Spanner via the CLI.

Now, this profile does make sense in some contexts. We keep another `gcloud` configuration for local testing, and in that case, we actually *do* want to disable auth and point calls to Cloud Spanner at an emulator running in a docker container. Obviously, this should not be the case in the `[default]` profile that is used to talk to real GCP.

The solution was to remove the offending config from that file so that it looks like:

```
[core]
account = username@domain.com
project = project-dev-gcp
```

Comment: Thank you. The issue was that I had an environment variable named ```GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS``` pointing to a credential file. I removed that after reading your response, and I could then do ```gcloud auth application-default login```

Answer (score 2):

I fixed this issue using

`gcloud config set auth/disable_credentials false`

Answer (score 1):

disable_credentials was set to true to run the pub-sub emulator or spanner locally. This was causing the auth failures in getting container cluster creds. After I set that above property to false, it was able to make live calls to the GCP to get the creds.

```
gcloud config set auth/disable_credentials false
```